# Verificar dinamicamente quais atributos de um Model foram alterados?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, asp.net-mvc-4

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação ASP.NET MVC 4 e preciso guardar o log de cada alteração feita num objeto do Model.

Existe algum método nativo ou implementação já conhecida que faça isso? *Exemplo:*

```
public class Pessoa
{
    public int? Id { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string SobreNome { get; set; }
}
```

Vamos supor que a pessoa modificou apenas o SobreNome quero saber o valor antigo o atual e que esse atributo foi alterado.

Comment: Você usa entity framework?
Se sim, pode usar esse projeto:
https://github.com/loresoft/EntityFramework.Extended/wiki/Audit-Log

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como não achei nada pronto na internet, com ajuda de um amigo, criamos uma classe e um método genérico para fazer isso:

```
public class AlteracaoLog
{
    public string ObjName { get; set; }
    public string Property { get; set; }
    public string OldValue { get; set; }
    public string NewValue { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Método para comparar diferenças entre dois objetos.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T1">Tipo do Objeto</typeparam>
    /// <param name="oldObj">Objeto Original</param>
    /// <param name="newObj">Objeto que você quer comparar</param>
    /// <param name="typeObj">Opcional, é usado quando a chamada é feita recursivamente</param>
    /// <returns>Array de AlteracaoLog</returns>
    public static AlteracaoLog[] Diff<T>(T oldObj, T newObj, Type typeObj = null)
    {
        var diffList = new List<AlteracaoLog>();

        var type = typeObj ?? typeof(T);

        foreach (var prop in type.GetProperties())
        {
            var _newValue = prop.GetValue(newObj, null);
            var _oldValue = prop.GetValue(oldObj, null);

            // Caso o objeto tenha uma propriedade que implemente a Interface "IBase"
            // Verifico as alterações desse objeto recursivamente e adiciono na Lista.
            if (prop.PropertyType.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(IBase)))
            {
                var tes = Diff(_oldValue, _newValue, prop.PropertyType);
                diffList.AddRange(tes);
            }
            else
            {
                if (!_newValue.Equals(_oldValue))
                {
                    diffList.Add(new AlteracaoLog
                    {
                        ObjName = type.Name,
                        Property = prop.Name,
                        OldValue = _oldValue.ToString(),
                        NewValue = _newValue.ToString()
                    });
                }
            }
        }
        return diffList.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Eu costumo usar o patern *Observer*.

> Observer é um Design Pattern que representa uma relação de 1-N (de um para muitos) entre objetos. Assim quando um objeto muda de estado os objetos dependentes serão notificados/informados e atualizados automaticamente. Este padrão permite que objetos sejam avisados da mudança de estado de outros eventos ocorrendo num outro objeto.
>
> Observer é também chamado de Publisher-Subscriber, Event Generator e Dependents.
>
> Os componentes desse patern são:
>
> - Subject
>
>   - Conhece os Observers. Qualquer número de objetos Observer pode observar um Subject.
>   - Fornece interfaces para anexar e desanexar objetos Observer.
> - ConcreteSubject
>
>   - Armazena estado de interesse para o ConcreteObserver.
>   - Envia a notificação para os observers quando o status muda.
> - Observer
>
>   - Define uma interface de atualização para objetos que devem ser notificados de mudanças em um Subject.
> - ConcreteObserver
>
>   - Mantém uma referência a um objeto ConcreteSubject.
>   - Armazena o estado que deve ficar consistente com o Subject.
>   - Implementa a interface *Observer* atualizando para manter o estado consistente com o Subject.

[Você pode olhar este link para ver um código de exemplo](http://csharpbrasil.com.br/observer/)

Comment: **Complementando:** existe o [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx) que faz isso também.

Comment: @NULL eu não trabalho com .net, por isso passei uma abordagem geral. Se achar interessante pode complementar minha resposta.

Answer (score 2):

Caso você esteja usando Entity Framework e a sua tentativa seja criar uma espécie de log de alterações, você pode sobrescrever o método `SaveChanges()` da sua implementação de `DbContext` e verificar as alterações no `ChangeTracker`:

```
    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        if (ChangeTracker.HasChanges())
        {
            var userLogado = System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal.Current.Identity.Name;
            var entries = ChangeTracker.Entries();
            foreach (var entry in entries)
            {                    
                if (entry.State == EntityState.Added)
                {
                }

                if (entry.State == EntityState.Deleted)
                {
                }

                if (entry.State == EntityState.Modified)
                {
                    //entry.OriginalValues; 
                    //entry.CurrentValues; 
                    //entry.Entity;                                                
                }
            }

        }

        return base.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Conforme vemos no trecho de código, é possível detectar em que estado de alteração `entry.State` se encontra uma entrada e verificar os valores originais `entry.OriginalValues` e atuais `entry.CurrentValues`, além do acesso à entidade `entry.Entity` em si.

Também no exemplo, `userLogado` dá acesso ao usuário que fez a alteração.

Por reflexão é possível comparar os valores originais e atuais para detectar apenas os campos modificados.

Comment: O que é este `ChangeTracker`?

Answer (score 1):

```
using System; 
using System.Collections; 
using System.Collections.Generic; 
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection; 
using System.Text; 
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CrashMemory
{
    public class AlteracaoLog
    {
        public string ObjName { get; set; }
        public string Property { get; set; }
        public string OldValue { get; set; }
        public string NewValue { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Método para comparar diferenças entre dois objetos.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T1">Tipo do Objeto</typeparam>
        /// <param name="oldObj">Objeto Original</param>
        /// <param name="newObj">Objeto que você quer comparar</param>
        /// <param name="typeObj">Opcional, é usado quando a chamada é feita recursivamente</param>
        /// <returns>Array de AlteracaoLog</returns>
        public static AlteracaoLog[] Diff<T>(T oldObj, T newObj, Type typeObj = null)
        {
            var diffList = new List<AlteracaoLog>();
            var type = typeObj ?? typeof(T);
            //var reg = type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.GetField);
            //var reg2 = type.GetProperties();

            //var propriedades = type.GetMembers(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.GetField).Where(a => a.MemberType == MemberTypes.Property || a.MemberType == MemberTypes.Field);
            foreach (var prop in type.GetFields())
            {
                var nome = prop.Name;
                //verificando se é um array ou lista 
                if (prop.GetValue(newObj).GetType().IsGenericType && prop.GetValue(oldObj).GetType().IsGenericType)
                {
                    //Tipo da lista ou tipo da classe do objecto
                    Type tipo = (Type)GetGenericCollectionItemType(prop.GetValue(newObj).GetType());

                    var oldObjField = (IList)prop.GetValue(oldObj);
                    var newObjField = (IList)prop.GetValue(newObj);
                    var tipoObjeto = prop.GetValue(newObj).GetType();

                    var countNewObjField = (int)tipoObjeto.GetProperty("Count").GetValue(newObjField, null);
                    var countOldObjField = (int)tipoObjeto.GetProperty("Count").GetValue(oldObjField, null);


                    if (countNewObjField > countOldObjField)
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < countNewObjField; i++)
                        {
                            if (i >= countOldObjField)
                            {
                                var instanciaNula = Activator.CreateInstance(tipo);
                                diffList.AddRange(Diff(instanciaNula, newObjField[i], newObjField[i].GetType()));
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                diffList.AddRange(Diff(oldObjField[i], newObjField[i], newObjField[i].GetType()));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else
                        if (countOldObjField > countNewObjField)
                        {
                            for (int i = 0; i < countOldObjField; i++)
                            {
                                if (i >= countNewObjField)
                                {
                                    var instanciaNula = Activator.CreateInstance(tipo);
                                    diffList.AddRange(Diff(oldObjField[i], instanciaNula, oldObjField[i].GetType()));
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    diffList.AddRange(Diff(oldObjField[i], newObjField[i], newObjField[i].GetType()));
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            for (int i = 0; i < countNewObjField; i++)
                            {
                                diffList.AddRange(Diff(oldObjField[i], newObjField[i], newObjField[i].GetType()));
                            }
                        }

                }
                else
                {
                    var _newValue = prop.GetValue(newObj);
                    var _oldValue = prop.GetValue(oldObj);
                    diffList.AddRange(Diff(_oldValue, _newValue, _oldValue.GetType()));
                }


            }






            foreach (var prop in type.GetProperties())
            {
                var _newValue = prop.GetValue(newObj, null);
                var _oldValue = prop.GetValue(oldObj, null);
                _newValue = _newValue == null ? "" : _newValue;

                if (!_newValue.Equals(_oldValue))
                {
                    diffList.Add(new AlteracaoLog
                    {
                        ObjName = type.Name,
                        Property = prop.Name,
                        OldValue = _oldValue == null ? "" : _oldValue.ToString(),
                        NewValue = _newValue == null ? "" : _newValue.ToString()
                    });
                }
                //}
            }
            return diffList.ToArray();
        }


        public static List<AlteracaoLog> FieldChanged(Type type, object newObj, object oldObj)
        {

            var fields = type.GetFields();
            var diffList = new List<AlteracaoLog>();
            foreach (var prop in fields)
            {
                var _newValue = prop.GetValue(newObj);
                var _oldValue = prop.GetValue(oldObj);
                diffList.AddRange(Diff(_oldValue, _newValue, _oldValue.GetType()));
            }
            return diffList.ToList();
        }

        static Type GetGenericCollectionItemType(Type type)
        {
            if (type.IsGenericType)
            {
                var args = type.GetGenericArguments();
                if (args.Length == 1 &&
                    typeof(ICollection<>).MakeGenericType(args).IsAssignableFrom(type))
                {
                    return args[0];
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Pode descrever quais foram suas alterações na resposta original?

Comment: Ola tudo bem? Verificação, se o objeto possui fields (foreach (var prop in type.GetFields()))  ex: pessoa {nome, idade ,List<Endereços>} uma pessoa que alem de nome e idade possui uma instancia do tipo endereço, anteriormente só verificava as propriedades,agora interage em outros objetos e listas da classe (ex: List<Endereços>})de forma recursiva e  independente do tamanho entre elas e verificação de valores nulos que podem acarretar exceções.