# Definição dos padrões Publisher-Subscriber e Observer

Tags: design-pattern, engenharia-de-software, observer-pattern

Hoje estava avaliando um [artigo](https://hackernoon.com/observer-vs-pub-sub-pattern-50d3b27f838c) (inglês) referente às diferenças entre os padrões Observer e Publisher-Subscriber, eu tinha até então a visão de que ambos eram a mesma coisa! Inclusive citando a própria [Wikipédia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer):

> O padrão Observer é também chamado de **Publisher-Subscriber**, Event
> Generator e Dependents.

No artigo o autor menciona que está foi uma questão de entrevista, e que ele respondeu que ambos eram iguais. A resposta do entrevistador foi de que eles NÃO eram iguais, segundo a definição do artigo:

> **Observer:** quando existe uma alteração em um objeto, os "observadores" são notificados
>
> **Publisher-Subscriber:** quando existe algum evento, um canal (tópico) é notificado, e todos os assinantes do tópico recebem a notificação. O notificante NÃO conhece seus notificados.

É confuso porque em alguns lugares mencionam que os dois padrões são iguais e a resposta pode ser considerada correta, por outro lado, a diferença de implementação mostra que são bem diferentes.

Ainda assim, no ponto de vista conceitual está correto dizer que o Publisher-Subscriber é uma "derivação" do padrão Observer e que NÃO são a mesma coisa, ou que são a mesma coisa?

Comment: Isto? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/36655/101 e isto? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/29046/101

Comment: @Maniero, complementei melhor a questão, estes dois links mencionam o Observer, mas a questão seria em como considerar conceitualmente dois padrões, ou apenas o Observer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O padrão Observer/Observable é principalmente implementado de uma maneira síncrona, ou seja, o observável chama o método apropriado de todos os seus observadores quando algum evento ocorre. Já no padrão Publisher/Subscriber é geralmente implementado de maneira assíncrona (usando a fila de mensagens).

No padrão do Observer/Observable, os observadores estão cientes do observável. Enquanto que no Publisher/Subscriber, os publishers e subscribers não precisam se conhecer. Eles simplesmente se comunicam com a ajuda de filas de mensagens.

Em resumo, são sim parecidos, porém existe essa sútil diferença entre eles.